# Is there any good ways to parse OpenSearch XML by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to parse OpenSearch XML to get a url for search like "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"

the XML is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
      <ShortName>Stack Overflow</ShortName>
      <Description>Search Stack Overflow: Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers</Description>
      <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
      <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico</Image>
      <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Comment: How do you get that XML to JavaScript?

Comment: Ah, so you dont need to "*parse*" it. Just use normal DOM traversing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var domParser = new DOMParser,
    dom = domParser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");

console.log( dom.getElementsByTagName("Url")[0].getAttribute("template"));
//"http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let the [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) do the work? I'm quite sure you don't get the XML as a string.

```
var dom = xhr.responseXML;
var url = dom.documentElement.querySelector("Url[template]"); // DOM lvl 3!
if (url)
    return url.getAttribute("template");
```